# Account Locking Not Working in WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I tired to lock user account using the admin console UI as described in http://isurad.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-lock-user-account-in-wso2.html. I made http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked = true. But still I can log in to the console using locked account.

Also tried to lock user account using the web service. Even this prints in the console,

```
{org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.services.UserIdentityManagementAdminService} -  User account unconfirmed1 locked
```

Still I can log in to the console using locked account. What has gone wrong here?

Comment: I also had problems with accountLocked claim. Please, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41662039/4141492) answer.

Answer (score 0):

The operation via the admin console is cached and is currently set to 15 mins. Hence the account lock should have worked but you need to wait 15 mins for this to come into effect. The web service calls should be immediate though.