# WSO2 IS SAML SSO Lock user from login

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml, wso2-identity-server

I have configured SAML SSO in WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 with my application. I want to have opportunity to lock/disable users from login with WSO2 login page.

How to solve this?

PS: Account Locked claim do not work. (work only for carbon login)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working, when adding Account Locked claim in Claim Configuration in Service Provider configuration.